# Symfony2 translations loaded but not translated

Tags: symfony, translation, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Im using FOS RestBundle and JMSSerializer (maybe its doing something i dont know) and want to returns a translated message in json. I wanted to use the translator service however the trans() method not working.

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('translator.key.here')
```

The translations seem to be loaded correctly as i dumped translator and found there the translated message under the current locale and 'translator.key.here' key. However the trans function simply gives back the key string.
Any idea?

Edit: In twig its working perfectly.
In my messages.hu yml file:

```
translator:
    key: 
        here: some message
```

In the config also set fallbacks:

```
translator: { fallbacks: [hu] }
default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

When i dumped translator in the object i found under en locale the right message key pair:

```
"translator.key.here" => "some message"
```

Comment: can you post your translation declaration ? did you enable the translator and the locale in the config ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Do i miss some option?

Comment: if you are using [hu] for fallbacks your messages file should be messages.hu. take a look at the [Translation process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-fallback)

Comment: If the message is located in the catalog, the translation is returned. If not, the translator returns the original message. This from the documentation.

Comment: Misspelled the file name sry ( i have hu and en also with the same keys just wanted to make it simple here).

Comment: Its getting even more strange to me.. In the midle of the controller if i dump($this->get('translator')); then it's catalogues array is empty however if call this dump in the same action but in the end of the controller in the exception catch block then the catalogues array contains the correct locale with the correct messages.. AND even it returns the key and not the translated message however right above the trans function the dumped translator object contains the mentoined catalogue

Answer (score 1):

Try this in parameters.yml:

```
locale: hu
```

and in config.yml:

```
framework:
     translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
     default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

and in translation folder create file: messages.hu.yml

Comment: This do the same as directly call $this->get() but gave it a try and the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a solution.. still dont know why not working simply but it works if i set directly the translation domain. 
translator->trans('key.goes.here', array(), 'messages);  if somebody has the some issue in the future.